# Overriding default Required ErrorMessage property in .NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have generated my DbContext using EF with DataAnnotations set and would like to override the Required ErrorMessage property using ModelMetadataType

eg

Generated class

```
public partial class ControlType
{
    public ControlType()
    {
        Rule = new HashSet<Rule>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ControlTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ControlType")]
    public virtual ICollection<Rule> Rule { get; set; }
}
```

My extension class

```
[ModelMetadataType(typeof(ControlTypeMeta))]
public partial class ControlType
{
}

public class ControlTypeMeta
{
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int ControlTypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Control type")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "'{0}' is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With the above I am expecting the Required ErrorMessage to be output as "'Control type' is required", but instead I get the default "The Control type field is required"

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how I can override the message (without creating view models)